# Restrict view movement between two others on MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE

Tags: android, touch, draggable

I want to make a view move under finger and also I want it stick in a height range between two views all the time.

Consider :

```
___________________________
|                          |
|            A             |
|__________________________|

           _____
           |_o_|

___________________________
|                          |
|            B             |
|__________________________|
```

I want View "o" move on touch between "A" and "B" vertically.

the problem is it seems ACTION_MOVE is not triggered all the time while moving so my if statement that checks the range not called so if you move the `o` view fast it goes out of range and then ACTION_MOVE trigger and View o stuck some where out of range. 
How can I do this.

My Code Snippet :

```
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        BeadView beadView = (BeadView) view;
        Rect parentRect = new Rect();
        Rect beadRect = new Rect();
        ((LinearLayout) beadView.getParent()).getGlobalVisibleRect(parentRect);
        beadView.getGlobalVisibleRect(beadRect);
        switch (motionEvent.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                dy = - Math.abs(beadView.getY() - motionEvent.getRawY());
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                if ((beadRect.bottom < parentRect.bottom) &&
                        beadRect.top > parentRect.top) {
                    beadView.animate()
                            .y(motionEvent.getRawY() + dy)
                            .setDuration(0).
                            start();
                }
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: try to debug with break points